# Сохранение файлов в Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: android, файлы, xamarin, forms, save

Друзья!

Не так давно увлекся разработкой для андроид,  пишу программу,  которая в конечном итоге должна выдать  файл  с определённым содержанием.

Проблема в том,  что я  хочу чтобы этот файл был сохранен  где-то  не в локальной папке приложение  и был виде пользователю через  проводник.

Экспериментировал с внутренним и внешним хранилищем,  однако не удалось добиться того,  чтобы  файл был виде пользователю.

Скажите,  как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно:

1. Получить разрешение на запись во внешнее хранилище.
2. Получить путь к внешнему хранилищу.
3. Записать файл по пути из п. 2, используя `StreamWriter`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Простой txt пишет, мне надо с помощью EPPLus создать файл excel и сохранить его, думаю тут тоже потоки надо использовать

Comment: Можете писать в основном потоке, можете в отдельном. Тут уже вопрос в том, как это вам нужно

Comment: Спасибо Вам,  все получилось,  всех благ

Comment: @АлексейГерасимов если помогло, поставьте галочку под ответом)